# how to apply security rules to specific collections

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a question about the security rules.

I know that we can do this to prevent unauthorized users for modifying any node in Firestore

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

What if I want to remove this prevention from certain root collections only?

I mean Lets say I have 2 root collections called Tracking, Incoming

Anyone can write or read to that as really no authentications is required for them. But all other collections need to have read/write done by only Authenticated users.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call them out and give access.  The most permissive rules will override all others.  Here, everyone has full access to documents in the collection called all-access:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
    match /all-access/{id} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

But you may want to consider if this is really a good idea. Anyone could jam billions of documents into the collection with these rules.  Think carefully about what you want everyone to be able to do here.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have 2 questions: Why do you have {id} basically what if I removed it, what happens.  And the second question,  I need to add a record in Incoming everytime a payment is received. This step happens before any user is authenticated. This is why I wanted to give global read/write. Any other idea?

Comment: You need some placeholder there to match any document that could be in the collection.  Your rules have to match a document.  Your second question should probably be a whole new question on SO with a complete description of what you need to accomplish without giving the world complete access to a collection.